# I am not able to clear my interval set with onmousedown with onmouseup

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to make my webpage more userfriendly for mobile and tabs, and I'm having this issue:

I want a button to increase a textbox value while the button is being pressed (onmousedown). So I created my button like this:

```
<span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full textIconBoxControll" 
    aria-hidden="true" 
    onmousedown="inter=setInterval(increaseFont, 300);"
    onmouseup="clearInterval(inter);" 
    onmouseout="clearInterval(inter);"> 

</span>
```

Now, when I press the button, it starts calling the increaseFont function, but it doesn't stop when I release the button or move the mouse out of the span. If I type this into my browser console (inter="setInter.." and clearInterval(inter);) it works as intended. I fear this has something to do with what scope "inter" belongs to when using the html events, but I cannot seem to find a solution to this. I've tried creating a global variable named inter in the top of my JS (doesn't work).

Comment: I would allow them to click the button for each size larger (or smaller). An interval on this is crazy.

Comment: I have a button for smaller as well, but since the increase is 0.1 pr click, and it ranges from 5 to 140. I don't want them to have to click up to 1350. That's why I want it to keep increasing while the button is held down.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me on a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LL09budf/). As you say, it may be something related to the scope of the `inter` variable, but then we'd need to see more of your code

Comment: I got it working. I had a span within my span (just for an icon to show), and I put the onmousedown action in both spans.. Removing this fixed everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` (you might want to use `ontouchstart`/`ontouchend`):

```
<button type='button' id='bigger'>Bigger</button>
<button type='button' id='smaller'>Smaller</button>
<br/>
<input type='text' id='num' value='5'/>

window.onload = function ol(){
    var bigger = document.getElementById('bigger'),
        smaller = document.getElementById('smaller'),
        num = document.getElementById('num'),
        max_num = 16.0,
        min_num = 5.0,
        speed = 30,
        step = .1,
        itv;

    bigger.onmousedown = go_bigger;
    bigger.onmouseup = reset;
    smaller.onmousedown = go_smaller;
    smaller.onmouseup = reset;

    function reset() {
        clearInterval(itv);
    }

    function go_bigger(){
        reset();

        itv = setInterval(function o(){
            var val = parseFloat(num.value, 10);

            if (val >= max_num) {
                reset();

                return;
            }

            val = Math.round((val + step) * 100) / 100;
            num.value = val;
            num.style.fontSize = val + 'px';
        }, speed);
    }

    function go_smaller(){
        reset();

        itv = setInterval(function o(){
            var val = parseFloat(num.value, 10);

            if (val <= min_num) {
                reset();

                return;
            }

            val = Math.round((val - step) * 100) / 100;
            num.value = val;
            num.style.fontSize = val + 'px';
        }, speed);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vcbhpzds/